# Sprite Asset Optimisation

Tags: 2d, android, spritesheet

I am writing a game for Android which combines open world questing and an RPG party development playstyle, and as such, I am finding it a very tight balancing act to get more content into that game that looks good, versus being limited with the amount of memory that an app can use without Android getting cranky about it.

I've been purchasing various assets to use for it, and have a good bunch of sprites to use, but when I wrote a calculator into my editor to instantly show me how much memory the bitmaps would consume when storing them I got some nasty shocks. So, I am looking to write some code into the editor first to at least optimise the size of each sprite frame in a model.

Some of the assets I have for example might have a spritesheet where the base sprite size is 300x300, even though the model itself is closer to 150 high. for example. I'm thinking of quickly parsing the spritesheet into the editor, checking to see if there are common areas of each sprite across the entire file that can be clipped - and then clip them out from every single sprite. That will leave me a sprite which has consistent sizing to the outer extremities of ANY of the sprites for that model. However, that means that individual sprites may still not be overly optimised.

In a well optimised engine, would each sprite be shrunk down to these minimal sizes and then rendered with offsets for each frame so that it appears centered - or would it be common practise to have each sprite in a single animation the same size, and just concede that there will be some animations that don't utilise the entire size of the bitmap and there will be sub-optimal memory usage for those?

An example would be a sprite where a character has both arms out, or both arms at their sides. In theory, when the arms are down, the width of the image could be narrower and rendered to account for that narrowing in that frame.

Comment: You tackle 2 issues here: 1 - it is generally worthless to ship game with assets that are bigger than they need to be, it's just a waste of space. You can easily "pre-process" all the assets into "correct" size on build. 2 - trimming sprites is an easy optimization, most of the games use it. thats why so many spritesheets are actually atlases (tightly packed).